# Stream closed exception is RestTemplate Java. How to pass multiplte objects to Java RestClient

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I am getting an unexpected error `java.io.IOException: Stream closed`

Error starts from this line

```
public void createPo(String username, PurchaseOrderDto po, List<PoItemDto> items) {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("poDto", po);
    params.put("items", items);
    rc.post(String.format("/po?username=%s", username), params);
}
```

`rc` is the rest client which calls the api from another server. Here is its code of its post function

```
protected void post(String path, Object object) {
restTemplate.postForObject((url + path), object, Void.class);
}
```

Following is the api which handles the above request `PoController.java`

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/po", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createPo(@RequestParam("username") String buyerId, @RequestBody PurchaseOrderDto poDto, @RequestBody List<PoItemDto> items) {
    poService.createPo(buyerId, poDto, items);
}
```

Logs from the tomcat server handling the request:

```
[http-bio-9080-exec-6]  ERROR ib.pms.controller.PoController - Stream closed java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.readByte(InputBuffer.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:106)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:139)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:105)
```

I can't make any sense out of this.
Is there a cleaner way to pass parameters to the restApi?

Comment: "IOException: Stream closed at" looks to me like the server receives an incomplete request. Have you tried to replay the request manually with curl, postman, your http tools of choice?

Comment: Yeah or that exception is more of a "something you get after another exception happened". Are there perhaps different exceptions in the logs prior to this one?

Comment: no, this one was the first exception thrown. this displays after that which seems to be of no use.
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodPr
ocessor.java:105)
        at org.spri

Comment: i am not sure if the way i'm sending data is correct or not. Can anybody comment on that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two `@RequestBody`, it's not possible, you should have one object `Foo` (implementing Serializable) containing `PurchaseOrderDto po, List<PoItemDto> items` and then passing `Foo` in your `restTemplate.postForObject`.

So, your controller has to be changed for something like:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/po", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createPo(@RequestParam("username") String buyerId, @RequestBody Foo foo) {
    poService.createPo(buyerId, foo.getDoDto(), foo.getItems());
}
```

I'm not sure it's going to fix your issue but at least it's one problem less

If you want to send multiple objects, you still can use a List:  `@RequestBody List<Foo> foos`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Apparently, api can't have multiple requestBody